Reassigning address ranges to child segments after breaking segment using FME
I have streets with LEFT and RIGHT address ranges assigned. Sometimes, I need to break the segment into 2 or more segments (for example, when a railway track is crossing the street).
How do I re-calculate the NEW address ranges for the NEWly created segments using FME?
For example, as shown in the image, the parent segment has address ranges of 0-100 and 1-99. After breaking it up into 2 segments, I expect to calculate and assign address ranges of 0-28, 1-29 and 30-100, 31-99 to the child segments.


using FME you need to rebuild the network topology see https://support.safe.com/hc/en-us/articles/25407613614093-Building-a-Topological-Network-from-a-Road-Dataset-Using-the-TopologyBuilder
